# AngularJS and Playframework integration

Tags: playframework, jasmine, angularjs

I'm trying to figure what is the best way of integrating my AngularJS and Play framework projects in order to package them together as front-end and back-end respectively.

I have found this [blog post](http://basav.github.com/blog/Angular-JS-Phonecat-example-with-Play-Framework/) talking about the exactly same problem but mine is slightly different because I'm using Play framework 1.2.5 instead of 2.0, thus I can't control the assets folder with:

> `GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

There is no evident/effective difference because the guy is exposing a lot of files that don't really are part of his application, the files under /public different of javascripts/, images/ and stylesheets/. That is what I would like to avoid, exposing such files in production or having to remove them before deploy to production.

It's worth mentioning that the files under /public different of javascripts/, images/ and stylesheets/ are AngularJS files/folders and mostly related to testing. AngularJS uses Jasmine internally to test (that is what I have read), so the files are Jasmine files disguised of AngularJS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I used Play 1.2.x, but you should be able to hide them from Production  in the routes file via a condition. Something like:

```
%{ if(Play.isProd() }%

    GET     /your-path-#1            404
    GET     /your-path-#2            404

%{ } else { }%
    GET     /your-path-#1            real path to file
%{ } }%
```

Be warned that the syntax will probably be wrong, it's been a long time, but that's the idea :)